# Automatically open downloaded file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS/Axios and have to implement a download file button.

My client requirement is when document is downloaded, it should automatically open with an appropriate program on the user's computer. For example when it is a Docx file and if the machine have MS Word, then open the doc automatically just after it is download.

NOTE: Even though in Chrome there is the option to set ***always open files of this type***, this is not an option. Have to consistently work in all  major browsers by default.

My code looks like below

```
   await axiosCall(urlForFileContent).then(function (response)
    {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        link.download = "TestFile.Docx";
        link.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)
    }
```

File can be a Docx, Pdf etc and the web service sets the correct MIME Type. I can see the download response contains correct "Content-Type" set when check in DevTools network section. e.g when it is a Docx,

```
Content-Type = application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

Thought when have correct MIME type it will work, But no. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: You are not in control over what happens on my computer. If I don't configure _my_ browser to handle downloads of a certain type in a certain way, then there is of course absolutely nothing you can do about that from your end. It would be a massive security issue, if _you_ could influence this.

Comment: Imagine you were using a Windows machine, and I offered you a download of a `.bat` file, that contains the command `del *.*`. `.bat` files are usually linked to the console (cmd.exe) as the "program" that can execute them. Now, do you really want _me_ to be in control of whether this will execute on your system automatically, without you getting any say in the matter ...?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too. Couldn't find anywhere a solution explains doing this. Because the web service is trusted and the content is legit, was asking to do it. Just wanted to see is that actually possible even when we sure about the content. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Even if it were, it would be a massive security risk, as the trusted site (whether by itself or by being hacked) could automatically download a visual basic script to your computer or a batch files, or any other type of malware that will automatically run automatically. You might be able to have a local program watch for downloads and open them, but you can't do it from a webpage.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's wat I thought as well. Here the scenarios is the content is coming from a trusted source and therefore to implement it. Wanted to be 100% sure if this is possible in any way.

Answer (score -4):

using `call %var%` will open the `filepath` `set` to `var`, you can also use `start` or `type`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).